# Why doesn't dropbox ask for a password when it starts up?

Tags: password-management

I don't want dropbox remembering my logon password.  It should have to be typed every time I log into it.  I don't see where to "do not remember me."  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you talking about the web application or the desktop client? In the latter case, please add the appropriate operating system tag to your question.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg "When it starts up" sounds like it's the desktop software.

Answer (score 2):

it saves your credential information. To "forget" your account on your machine -- right click the Dropbox icon in the task tray --> Preferences --? Account --> Unlink This Computer.

Then exit dropbox (right click --> Exit) then relaunch the app and it should be like when it was first installed (Do you have an account? Y/N - wizard setup).

Answer (score 2):

Dropbox assumes you sync it with your own computer. In this case you can simply password-protect your computer/system account and change Dropbox folder permissions.

If you're using Dropbox on a public computer then I don't know why you'd want to sync entire Dropbox. You can simply download the files you need through their website and it won't remember you.